# i have a error using dt.date on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to get rid of the hours and minutes in the pandas dataframe and convert them to days. The value type in the data is datetime.datetime but when I use the .dt.date function it gives an error.here is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['45259191000','45488870311'], 'time': ['2022-10-04 08:57:00', '2022-10-07 11:17:00']})
print(type(df.iat[0, 0]))
df['new'] = df['time'].dt.date
display(df)
```

this code returns **Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike value**
and my datatype <class 'datetime.datetime'> thank you in advance. i hope answer is not very obvious.

Comment: Could you post a snippet where your issue is reproducible? Currently the dates in the dataframe are of type string, which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the 'time' column to pandas datetime before you work with it:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```